# Como "criar" uma variável em "runtime"?

Tags: c++, estrutura-de-dados, variáveis

Eu estou fazendo um projeto que implementa um console ao estilo Python. Tem várias funções, tem muitas coisas. Mas eu preciso implementar um comando chamado `set`. `set` declararia uma cadeia de caracteres e definiria seu valor conforme o usuário definisse.

```
class Variavel
{
    private:
    char* nome;
    char* valor;
    public:
    Variavel() : nome(NULL), valor(NULL)
    {
    }
    ~Variavel()
    {
        delete[] nome;
        delete[] valor;
    }
    void DefVar(const char* valor, const char* nome)
    {
        this->valor = new char[strlen(valor)];
        this->valor = const_cast<char*>(valor);
        this->nome = new char[strlen(nome)];
        this->nome = const_cast<char*>(nome);
    }
};
```

Eu poderia criar um array grande ou um ponteiro, e a cada instância que o cliente definisse mais uma variável, o número do array aumentasse. Quando ele pedisse uma variável, mapearia cada array até o fim. É um método que funciona, mas é muito lento, gasta muita memória e é um pouco ineficiente. Como criar uma variável em runtime de uma maneira eficiente?

Comment: Melhorou com o construtor e o destrutor, mas você ainda tem que desabilitar o construtor de cópia, ou implementar um, senão vai acabar com dois objetos apontando para os mesmo buffers, o que vai gerar `delete's` duplicados. Por isso o `std::string` é mais prático, como já comentado.

Comment: E tem mais um motivo para você usar std::string. A sua função DefVar tá com memory leak. Você está definindo valor e nome sem liberar o que valor e nome já guardavam.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode usar um [`std::map`](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) para guardar sua tabela de variáveis. Exemplo:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::string Variable;

std::map<std::string, Variable> table;
table["x"] = "1+1";
table["y"] = "1-1";
std::cout << table["x"] << std::endl; // 1+1
```

Existem muitas classes na biblioteca padrão para fazer esse tipo de gerenciamento. Observe a [biblioteca de containers](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

---

Tem vários outro problemas na sua classe `Variavel`. Em primeiro lugar você guarda ponteiros para dados que você alocou (ou seja, você é o **dono** desses recursos) e como tal, é sua a responsabilidade de os liberar. É preciso que se defina um destrutor `delete`ando os os ponteiros.

Também, não há um construtor padrão, então o compilador criará um em branco para você que **não** inicializa os ponteiros. Então nesse caso eles vão apontar para uma memória qualquer inválida. Você deve definir um construtor padrão (ou algum outro). A função `DefVar` por exemplo deveria ser um construtor.

Para que o objeto tenha semânticas de valor (poder ser tratado como os tipos primitivos), deve também ter um construtor de cópia, que duplicará a alocação e um `operator=` que tem operação semelhante ao construtor de cópia.

Isso é chamado: **Regra dos Três**. (Ou **Regra dos Cinco** no C++11 por conta de poder mover objetos).

Ou mais fácil que isso: utilize `std::string` como fiz no meu exemplo que já implementa tudo que você precisa e tem semânticas de valor. Muito mais simples e confiável que usar meros ponteiros diretamente.

Comment: A classe Variavel é apenas ilustrativa.

Answer (score 2):

O contêiner mais eficiente para guardar-se muitos objetos é o `std::vector`. Internamente ele é apenas um array. Se você vai precisar fazer pesquisas nele, pode tornar isso eficiente usando o algoritmo `std::lower_bound` para fazer a inserção dos elementos de forma ordenada no vector, e depois também para fazer a pesquisa.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Variavel {
    std::string nome, valor;

    Variavel(const std::string &nome, const std::string &valor="")
      : nome(nome), valor(valor) {
    }
};

//necessário para ordenar as variáveis no vector
bool operator<(const Variavel &lhs, const Variavel &rhs) {
    return lhs.nome < rhs.nome;
}

std::vector<Variavel> variaveis;

//adiciona uma variável
void setVar(const std::string &nome, const std::string &valor) {
    Variavel v(nome, valor);
    //Posição onde se adicionar para que a lista fique em ordem
    std::vector<Variavel>::iterator pos = std::lower_bound(variaveis.begin(), variaveis.end(), v);
    variaveis.insert(pos, v);
}

//Obtem uma variável. Retorna ponteiro nulo caso nao exista
const Variavel *getVar(const std::string &nome) {
    std::vector<Variavel>::iterator pos = std::lower_bound(variaveis.begin(), variaveis.end(), Variavel(nome));
    if (pos != variaveis.end() && pos->nome == nome) {
        return &(*pos);
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Provavelmente no futuro você vai adicionar mais conteúdo à classe variável, como seu tipo. Se ela ficar muito grande pode valer a pena transformá-la em um *wrapper* para uma classe alocada dinamicamente, minimizando assim o efeito das cópias de objetos. Mas se você já estiver trabalhando com C++11 esse problema é minimizado.

Comment: Nota: Inserir e acessar elementos em um `std::map` tem complexidade logarítmica  (`O(log n)`), enquanto que o `std::vector::insert` é linear (`O(n)`) mesmo que a busca pelo `std::lower_bound` seja logarítmica. Outro problema está em inserir duas variáveis com o mesmo nome.

Comment: Sim, ele vai ter que por na balança o processamento x consumo de memória. Sobre a inserção de elementos repetidos bastaria checar pelo campo nome, como foi feito na hora de se buscar o elemento, não coloquei para não estender mais ainda o exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

O que você quer criar é uma tabela de símbolos para o seu interpretador.
No nível mais baixo, isso é um mapa de strings (nomes das variáveis) para endereços de memória:

```
std::map<std::string, void*> tabelaSimbolos;
```

Dessa forma, cada variável declarada seria alocada em uma área, com algum tipo qualquer.
Para elaborar um pouco mais (e que provavelmente será necessário), você vai precisar de informações sobre esse símbolo. Então você vai precisar de uma estrutura de dados, dizendo qual o tipo da sua variável e onde estão os dados efetivamente. Uma estrutura parecida com:

```
class Variavel {
  std::string tipo;
  void* dados;
};
```

E seu mapa mudaria para:

```
std::map<std::string, Variavel*> tabelaSimbolos;
```

Assim, para cada variável, você acessaria a estrutura correspondente, e saberia com qual tipo deveria interpretar os dados. Seu mapa ficaria por exemplo:

```
tabelaSimbolos["minhaString"] = {"string", 0x100000} 
tabelaSimbolos["meuInt"] = {"int", 0x2000000}
```

Isso é só um começo, e bem primitivo. Lembrando que você vai quase certamente ter que lidar com alocações dinâmicas, pesquise sobre RAII pra evitar dores de cabeças com news e deletes.